# How to permanently remove a particular Chrome notification from Android mobile phone?

Tags: notifications, chrome-for-android

I visited a website yesterday. Today, a notification popups every time my mobile phone is rebooted, showing me that website (it is grouped under "Social digest"). However, when I click on that notification, it only takes me to Chrome but not to that website.

How to permanently remove this notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **Chrome → Settings → Site settings (under "Advanced") → Notifications** and click on it.

The following screen will appear

> [image: Per-site notification setting on Chrome]

If you turn off the **Notifications slider**, you will not get any notification from Chrome at all (from sites).

To turn off for a particular site, click on **Allowed → [URL of the site] → Notifications (under "Permission")** → change **"Allow"** to **"Block"**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete notifications for specific sites in the list. You have to manage in storage of application by going **Android's Settings > Apps > Chrome > Storage > Manage Space > Manage**.

From there, select the domain URLs that you do not want individually, which will show its **"Site settings"**, then select the **trash can** next to **"Usage"** and select **"Clear all"**.

Comment: i dont think it works though

Comment: Im on a samsung s10. I went to storage>manage storage on bottom left>    then clicked free up space and manage. not sure if clear all data is good to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the **"More info"** section of the Chrome app (**Android's Settings > Application Manager > Chrome**), uncheck **"Show notifications"**. This will turn off all notifications for Chrome.

Comment: In the "Settings", I have "Basics" and "Advanced". In the "Basics", I have "Search engine", "Auto-fill forms" and "Save passwords". In the "Advanced", I have "Privacy", "Accessibility", "Site settings", "Date saver" and "About Chrome". I cannot find "application manager".

Answer (score 0):

I have at last worked out how to remove notifications permanently from Chrome on Android:

1. Press the three dots at the top-right of Chrome
2. Go to Settings
3. Select Notifications
4. Scroll all the way to the bottom and press the Advanced button, then press Additional settings
5. Now you should find yourself in the notifications section of Chrome. You can see both Blocked and Allowed notifications by going through the different addresses
6. Click on each of the sites you wish to remove, you will be given the option:
   Clear and Reset - press this if you want to remove the notification from your phone in its entirety

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Google is continuously moving this setting. As of today, this is how I removed the notification settings for a specific site. I'm on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 lite.

1. Three dots at top right
2. Settings
3. Site settings
4. All sites
5. Select specific site
6. Clear & reset