# How to remove Chrome's per-site notification entry on the Android settings?

Tags: notifications, settings, chrome-for-android

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S10. Sometimes when I visit "certain" websites, the site requests to send notifications to me through Chrome.

[image]

How do I remove these Chrome site notification requests from random websites on the Android settings? I don't see any locations for removal.

This is similar but not the same to [How to permanently remove a particular Chrome notification from Android mobile phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170057/how-to-permanently-remove-a-particular-chrome-notification-from-android-mobile-p) since that question is asking to remove the notifications only, not the entry on the settings.

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to remove those notification entries of websites from that Settings page?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the entries.

Comment: [One of the later answers to the linked question](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/222285/44325) should also solve this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove notifications for an individual site on Chrome for Android, you need to block the Notification permission by doing the following:

1. Open Chrome -> Settings.
2. In the Advanced section, click on Site Settings, then All Sites. Sites that have permissions set will be listed.
3. Find the site you are looking for, click on it.
4. Under the Permissions section, click on the permissions you want to remove, in your case the Notification permission, then select "Block".

To remove the entries:

1. Open Chrome -> Settings.
2. Site Settings -> Data stored -> Clear all data.

This [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171030/247431) from a previous question (linked by OP) is actually better than my suggestion as it will remove only the notification entries.